# What is meant by reversing the orientation of an oriented manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, orientation

Trying to understand the following statement, I hope my stupid question won't bother you too much. Thank you.

> **Proposition.** *Let $M$ be an oriented smooth $n$-manifold and let $\omega$ be a compactly supported $n$-form on $M$. If $-M$ denotes $M$ with the opposite orientation, then
> $$\int_{-M}\omega=-\int_M\omega.$$*

I'm not sure if I understand the meaning of the notation $-M$ correctly. Does it signify that each tangent space $T_p M$ is endowed with **the other** orientation $-\mu_p$? Here $\mu_p$ denotes the original orientation on $T_p M$. (every finite-dimensional vector space has **exactly two** orientations)

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming an _orientation_ is defined to be a consistent collection of orientations on the tangent spaces, then "yes." (If an _orientation_ is a non-vanishing form of top degree, i.e., an oriented manifold is a pair $+M := (M, \mu)$, then "$-M$" would be $(M, -\mu)$, and so forth.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you. An orientation on a vector space $V$ is an equivalence class of bases for $V$.